# Forward RDP Connection from Server to Client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

What I'm trying to achieve is in the following infrastructure:

```
Server A running ADDS, DNS, DHCP, NPS
LAN
-Computer Client I
-Computer Client II

Server A NIC 1 goes to LAN
Server A NIC 2 goes to Internet
Server A provides DHCP and Internet access for Computer Clients
```

How do I connect to Computer Client I or II through RDP from outside the network? Even when using credentials from Computer Client I (which are not in ADDS) the connection still only goes to the server.

Comment: You need more detail on your question, otherwise nobody is going to want to risk downvotes by trying to answer with the good possiblity of not completely understanding your question...

Answer (score 3):

> How do I connect to Computer Client I or II through RDP from outside the network?

If your server is doing NAT, then you cannot connect to the boxes behind it directly.

- You can RDP to the server, and then start another RDP from the server to one of your clients.
- You can setup a the [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560672%28WS.10%29.aspx) service on your server, and configure the RDP gateway in your client.
- You can setup A VPN to the server which gives you an IP address on the internal network.
- You can setup some 3rd party basic tunnel like SSH.

Comment: +1 for Remote Desktop Gateway.

Comment: I've achieved option 1 but that doesn't solve the problem. I also have a VPN setup. I'm going to try the Remote Desktop Gateway! Thank you

Comment: The benefit of using RDP gateway is that you only need to open port 443 on the gateway and not expose 3389 on the server.  The less exposure the better.  It works well, and my users are much happier with this.  Just keep in mind that if you plan on doing this from a mac or other non windows box, you will need a client that supports RDP gateway  (iphone/ipad can use itap,  android can use Remote Desktop by Xtralogic).